# Looping through sheets removing duplicates

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

My code seems to be working. I want to check for improvements, potential bugs and unintended consequences.

I have spreadsheets with duplicate information, some have 100 sheets inside each file.

I don't want to go through each sheet manually using remove duplicate information.

After searching I think I have a solution.

```vb
Sub RemoveDuplicates()
 ' RemoveDuplicates Macro
 ' Selects all values then removes duplicates
 '

     ' Declare Current as a worksheet object variable.
         Dim Current As Worksheet
         Dim starting_ws As Worksheet
         Set starting_ws = ActiveSheet 'remember which worksheet is active in the beginning

         ' Loop through all of the worksheets in the active workbook.
         For Each Current In Worksheets
            Current.Activate
            
            LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            ActiveSheet.Range("A1" & LastRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11), Header:=xlYes
      
         Next
         
    starting_ws.Activate 'activate the worksheet that was originally active
    
End Sub
```

I am only looking for duplicates on each sheet, not comparing worksheets. Also the number of columns will stay the same.

Comment: It could help to have a picture of sample spreadsheets to better understand what you're referring as duplicate values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Remove Duplicates (Multiple Columns and Worksheets)

- Use `Option Explicit`.
- This `ActiveSheet.Range("A1" & LastRow)` is surely wrong. Think about it.
- You have to qualify `Range`, `Cells`, `Rows` and `Columns` e.g. `Current.Cells`, `Current.Rows.Count`...
- You don't have to activate `Current`. `Current` is the `ActiveSheet` in your case (since you have activated it), so no need to use `ActiveSheet` instead.
- Do not let `Excel` to define the range: you define it.

**A Code With a Question**

```
Option Explicit

Sub removeDupes()
     
     ' Here's a question:
     '     Why can't I use 'Cols' instead of the array written explicitly?
     Dim Cols As Variant
     Cols = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11)
     
     Const FirstAddress As String = "A1"
     Dim wb As Workbook
     Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
     
     Dim ws As Worksheet
     Dim LastCell As Range
     
     For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
         Set LastCell = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(, 10)
         ws.Range(FirstAddress, LastCell).RemoveDuplicates _
             Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11), Header:=xlYes
         ' This doesn't work.
         'ws.Range(FirstAddress, LastCell).RemoveDuplicates _
             Columns:=Cols, Header:=xlYes

         ' Try this with ByVal array.
         'ws.Range(FirstAddress, LastCell).RemoveDuplicates _
             Columns:=(Cols), Header:=xlYes
     Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Just looked up what Option Explicit is, very useful, it think I did see it in code samples i was referring too. I see what you mean about referencing a cell then a row. I kept chopping and changing with using current then activesheet, I understand my mistake there. And I do find it strange you have to use an explicit array for the columns. So I assume from your example that using ws.Rows.Count will count just the rows with data in it? Excellent reply thanks again,

Comment: Since `Excel 2007`, `ws.Rows.Count` (`Rows.Count` in a worksheet) means row `1048576`, so it's actually the last cell in column `A`: cell `A1048576`. Only the End(xlUp) 'jumps' up to the last non-empty cell. It is equivalent to pressing `CRTL`+`UP`. And finally `Offset(, 10)` or `Offset(0, 10)` means ten columns to the right to determine the cell in the same row but in column `K`, so in the next line (`ws.Range(FirstAddress, LastCell)...`) we can define the complete range: from `A1 to KwhateverRow`.

Comment: Excellent thanks! That explains perfectly clearly what those are doing. Thank you for helping a complete beginner to vba like me. @VBasic2008

Comment: @VBasic2008 I believe it is considered good practice to set objects to nothing at the end of your methods. For example, just before your End Sub above, you could put this line: Set wb = Nothing: Set ws = nothing

Comment: Thanks for taking an interest, but that's out of the question: [Have a read](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bvba%5d%20releasing%20object%20variables). Also, I have approved your edit, but haven't still tested if a zero-based array may be necessary as Variatus suggested in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66915003/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows-from-an-excel-worksheet-using-a-dynamic-column-a/66915971#66915971) to *How can I remove duplicate rows from an Excel worksheet using a dynamic column array?*.