# AutoFilter used to work but now gives error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

So, the code used to work just fine. I tested it a lot before. But now the error just started happening.

My goal is to open another workbook (our Gantt database), aply 3 different filters and then circle through all the visible rows searching and specific values and pasting them into the objective workbook.

I already tried adding codes to remove and then to input the autofilters again, i tried changing the cell reference in criteria2 to value (i.e. "11/30/2020") but the error kept occuring. I hope you all can help me, 'cause i saw iall over the internet this is a hard solving and really specific problem.

The comented code:
Sub Gantt()

```
    Dim i, limite As Long
    Dim Wko, Wkd As Workbook
    Dim WksO, WksP As Worksheet
    
    Set Wkd = Workbooks("MC Produção TOTAL.xlsb") 'my objective workbook
    Set WksP = Wkd.Worksheets("BD_Resumo") 'worksheet to paste some gathered database
    Set WksOp = Wkd.Worksheets("Operação") 'workshett where i control what's happening
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="M:\apoio_manutencao\03 - Relatórios\2 - Custos\Banco de Dados PA.*", ReadOnly:=True 'open the database workbook
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                         
    Set Wko = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
    Set WksO = Wko.Worksheets("Banco de Dados") 'where the data comes from

    i = 5

    If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
    WksO.ShowAllData 'here I make sure there is no filter applied, but autofilter is still there to be used
    End If

    limite = WksO.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'pick the last row with values on my database workbook

    '!!!!ERROR HAPPENS HERE!!!

    WksO.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(limite, 41)).AutoFilter Field:=21, Operator:= _
    xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(1, WksOp.Range("K2").Text)                        'adds filter by date (in the range i have the value of the last day of the month 11/30/2020)
    
    '!!!!YEP, RIGHT ABOVE, ON THE FIRST FILTER!!!

    WksO.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(limite, 41)).AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:= _
    "Produção"                                                                          'Add the second filter
    WksO.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(limite, 41)).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array( _
    "Emblistamento", "Encapsulamento", "Envase"), Operator:=xlFilterValues              'add the third filter

    While WksP.Cells(i, 1) <> "" 'i have a group of TAGs that I want to use as final decision for gathering the info I want

        WksO.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(limite, 41)).AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:= _
            WksP.Cells(i, 1).Value  'adds the last filter, the TAG I want to see at the moment
        WksP.Cells(i, 7).Value = 0

 For Each Cell In WksO.Range(Cells(2, 22), Cells(limite, 22)) 
        If Cell.Rows.Hidden = False And IsNumeric(Cell.Value) Then 'it will only work with visible cells that contain numeric values
                WksP.Cells(i, 7).Value = WksP.Cells(i, 7).Value + Cell.Value * 24 'i made previous sure that my objective cell is empty and than i can add the new values. I multiply because i am talking in decimal hours
        End If
 Next
    i = i + 1
    Wend

    WksP.Range("G5:G32").NumberFormat = "0.00"     'just to make sure my decimal numbers have only 2 numbers afeter "."
    Wko.Close SaveChanges:=False 'I don't want to mess with my original archive

    End Sub
```

I know it is a big code, but I also don't know waht else to do. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Probably just a typo: You cannot set `Criteria2` as filter criteria, you should use `Criteria1`. `Criteria2` is used only for between filter.

Comment: The thing is, this is made ith the macro recorder (except for the cell reference, that is what I changed, the macro recorder made it with a date instead). And it used to work this exact way I posted. I had already tried changing it before, but I did it again just in case. By doing it the program gives no error. But it also finds nothing. In order to figure what was happening I made the code stop right before this code line and run step by step. The filter hides all my data, I supose `criteria2` is the correct to be used.
But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I think you should change `criteria2` to `criteria1`. But have you tried `WksOp.Range("K2").Value` (`.Value2`) or `CStr(WksOp.Range("K2").Value)` instead of `WksOp.Range("K2").Text` and/or `"1"` instead of `1`? Note that this `WksO.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(limite, 41)).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array( _
    "Emblistamento", "Encapsulamento", "Envase"), Operator:=xlFilterValues` is working.

Comment: I will post below all the combined attempts trying your suggestions @VBasic2008. Unfortunately neither have worked. The thing about `Criteria2` is that it is used as only criteria when filtering by date. I am trying to filter by month. We can see more details here [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter).

**My attempts and their results:**
First attempt: `WksO.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(limite, 41)).AutoFilter Field:=21, Operator:=  xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=Array("1", WksOp.Range("K2").Value)`
Result: hides everything

Comment: **continuing attempts**
Second: `WksO.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(limite, 41)).AutoFilter Field:=21, Operator:= _
        xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array("1", WksOp.Range("K2").Value)`
Result: returns the same 1004 error
Third : `WksO.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(limite, 41)).AutoFilter Field:=21, Operator:= _
        xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(1, WksOp.Range("K2").Value)`
Result: same 1004 error
Fourth: `WksO.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(limite, 41)).AutoFilter Field:=21, Operator:= _
        xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(1, CStr(WksOp.Range("K2").Value))`
Result: same 1004 error

Comment: **continuing attempts:**
**sixth:** `WksO.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(limite, 41)).AutoFilter Field:=21, Operator:= _
        xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=Array("1", CStr(WksOp.Range("K2").Value))`
result: hides everything
**seventh:** `WksO.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(limite, 41)).AutoFilter Field:=21, Operator:= _
        xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=Array("1", CStr(WksOp.Range("K2").Value2))`
result: 1004 error
**eighth:** `WksO.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(limite, 41)).AutoFilter Field:=21, Operator:= _
        xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=Array("1", WksOp.Range("K2").Value2)`
result: 1004 error

Comment: So, any other idea? I m still stuck with this

Comment: @FunThomas: Did you know about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65241938/autofilter-used-to-work-but-now-gives-error-1004/65309109#65309109)? I didn't, now I do.

Comment: Interesting is that if I record a macro apllying the filter and just run it, it will return the same error. Just as answered here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28575754/filter-out-multiple-criteria-using-excel-vba) by @aucuparia. I will try some alternative. If i succeed I will post it here.

Answer (score 0):

### AutoFilter: Criteria2 for Dates - International Issue

**Criteria2**

- **Microsoft Docs about Criteria2 of [`Range.AutoFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter):**
  *The second criteria (a string). Used with Criteria1 and Operator to construct compound criteria. **Also used as single criteria on date fields filtering by date, month or year. Followed by an Array detailing the filtering Array(Level, Date). Where Level is 0-2 (year,month,date) and Date is one valid Date inside the filtering period.***

**The Solution**

```
WksO.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(limite, 41)).AutoFilter _
    Field:=21, _
    Operator:=xlFilterValues, _
    Criteria2:=Array(1, Format(WksOp.Range("K2").Value, "m\/d\/yyyy"))
```

**Two Examples**

```
Option Explicit

Sub testOneDate()
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim mDate As Date: mDate = DateSerial(2020, 2, 1)
    Dim usDateString As String: usDateString = Format(mDate, "m\/d\/yyyy")
    
    Debug.Print rng.Address
    Debug.Print mDate
    Debug.Print usDateString
        
    rng.Worksheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    ' Filter by month of Date (February):
    rng.AutoFilter _
        Field:=2, _
        Operator:=xlFilterValues, _
        Criteria2:=Array(1, usDateString)

End Sub

Sub testTwoDates()
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim FirstDate As Date: FirstDate = DateSerial(2020, 2, 1)
    Dim SecondDate As Date: SecondDate = DateSerial(2020, 4, 1)
    Dim usFirst As String: usFirst = Format(FirstDate, "m\/d\/yyyy")
    Dim usSecond As String: usSecond = Format(SecondDate, "m\/d\/yyyy")
    
    Debug.Print rng.Address
    Debug.Print FirstDate, SecondDate
    Debug.Print usFirst, usSecond
        
    rng.Worksheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    ' Filter by months of Dates (February and April):
    rng.AutoFilter _
        Field:=2, _
        Operator:=xlFilterValues, _
        Criteria2:=Array( _
            1, Format(FirstDate, "m\/d\/yyyy"), _
            1, Format(SecondDate, "m\/d\/yyyy"))
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not solve. I even tried some variations after the first fail. Even tried putting my cell to show the date as "m/d/yyyy". Nothing changed. I found a way of doing my logic without this autofilter. It takes 5 minutes longer to finish but i did it.
At the end, in my "For each cell" there is a If, i added some "and's" and it ended like: `If cell.Rows.Hidden = False And IsNumeric(cell.Value) And Year(WksO.Cells(cell.Row, 21).Value) = Year(WksOp.Range("K2").Value) And Month(WksO.Cells(cell.Row, 21).Value) = Month(WksOp.Range("K2").Value) Then`. I still accept new ideas :D

Comment: For my solution to work, you have to have a date in `K2`. You could try the test procedures in a new workbook. Just write some headers, write some dates in february and april to column `B` of a worksheet and fill the rest with some dummy data. Then goto VBE and run the `testOneDate` and `testTwoDates` procedures. I would appreciate some feedback.

Comment: Yeah, I made sure my K2 value is a date.I also created a excel (to test your codes) with dummy data in column 1 and 3 ("A" and "C") and in the column 2 ("B") i put only date, variyng through all the months on the year. It still returned the same 1004 error. I don't know if you checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28575754/filter-out-multiple-criteria-using-excel-vba), the first answer goes about a possible Bug in vba and excel where something can only be done through the user interface. Even if you try to use the macro recorder it will return a error.

Comment: The problem is that it's working on my end. Here is a link to [my file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WgrENccm2uJUtviT6ILHqkleVJ0CRctN/view?usp=sharing) on `Google Drive`. Could you share which versions of `Windows` and `Office` you are using? I'm using `Windows 10 64-bit` and `Office 2019 32-bit`. BTW I had a similar experience [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65049675/vba-looping-through-sheets-removing-duplicates/65050972#65050972).

Comment: I am using the `Office Home and business 2019 32-bit` and `Windows 10 64-bit`. My `VBA` (i suppose it is the same buuut) `version 1104, retail 7.1.1104, Forms3 16.0.13127.20204`. Anyway, just really understand the meaning of "option explicit" and I will definetely start using it. I like to declare everything, but somethings may escape my mind. Unfortunately I downloaded your archive and just ran it, and the same eror happened. Is it possible my vba is missing some library?

Comment: Based on your code and some internet examples I made a adptation that seems to work.
`rng.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=">=02/01/2020", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="` `<=02/29/2020"`
Using criteria 1 and 2 and putting my date limits (wich I previously know) it is possible to use the autofilter without errors! 
Thank you all for the help. I learned a lot! If you all wish to stop here I will understand. But I am still curious to know and solve the 1004 error problem, and willing to help search it!