# How can I remove duplicate rows from an Excel worksheet using a dynamic column array?

Tags: excel, vba

The Microsoft Docs for [Range.RemoveDuplicates method (Excel)]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.removeduplicates all display a syntax with a hard coded array of column numbers as seen below.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:C100").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1,2), Header:=xlYes
```

But how can I use the above syntax with a dynamic column array? I tried defining integer and variant arrays, but each would give runtime errors.

Answer (score 1):

It would be a rare occasion when you would have to define a duplicate as "when all values in a row are identical with all values in another row". The more frequent case is to have a number or a name, perhaps in combination with a first name and/or a birthday, in short, selected columns which can't be expected to be adjacent. Excel's `RemoveDuplicate` function accommodates that requirement.

However, if indeed you would face the task of creating an array of many consecutive numbers, here is a very simple function that does the job in Excel. (Observe that it doesn't need to be declared `Public`.)

```
Private Function ColumnsArray(ByVal Cstart As Long, _
                              ByVal Cend As Long) As Variant
    
    Dim Fun As Variant          ' function return array
    Dim i   As Long             ' Fun index
    Dim Tmp As Variant
    
    Tmp = "Row(" & Cstart & ":" & Cend & ")"
    Tmp = Application.Evaluate(Tmp)
    ReDim Fun(0 To UBound(Tmp) - 1)
    For i = 1 To UBound(Tmp)
        Fun(i - 1) = Tmp(i, 1)
    Next i
    ColumnsArray = Fun
End Function
```

The function includes a conversion of the 1-based array returned from Excel to a 0-based array required by VBA for use in the `Columns` argument. Note that the array must also be passed `ByVal` as indicated by the enclosing parentheses in the function call shown below.

```
Dim Arr As Variant
Arr = ColumnsArray(2, 4)
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:D100").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=(Arr), Header:=xlYes
```

Comment: Have you tested it with `RemoveDuplicates`? In [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65049675/vba-looping-through-sheets-removing-duplicates/65050972#65050972) it didn't work no matter how many columns in the array (look for *This doesn't work near the end of the code*). Would appreciate some feedback either way.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Thank you for pointing this out. I have modified my reply in response to your query and explained the reasons and solutions above.

Comment: Unbelievable. You have cracked it. Thanks a lot. Looking forward to testing it. No time at the moment.

Comment: @Variatus Thanks for the additional explanation. I had missed that the columns array needed to be passed ByVal. Your example is still hard coded to 2, 4. I need it to be dynamic for reusability. It is not uncommon to have to cleanse csv data coming from an external source.

Comment: As I have explained, this kind of function is intrinsically custom tailored. Start and End are hard-coded in your example, too. But if you want a function that extracts them from a worksheet of variable size I suggest you pass the sheet as argument and then `With Ws.UsedRange: Cstart = .Column: Cend = .Columns.Count - .Column + 1: End With`.

Answer (score -1):

The secret is to pass an embedded function to return a variant array of column numbers:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:C100").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=CustomFunction, Header:=xlYes
```

Here is my custom function that returns a variant array of column numbers.

```
Public Function GetColumnsArray(lBegCol As Long, lEndCol As Long) As Variant
Dim lIndex As Long, lCol As Long
Dim vColumnsArray As Variant
    lCol = lBegCol
    ReDim vColumnsArray(lEndCol - lBegCol)
    For lIndex = LBound(vColumnsArray) To UBound(vColumnsArray)
        vColumnsArray(lIndex) = lCol
        lCol = lCol + 1
    Next

    GetColumnsArray = vColumnsArray
End Function
```

And here is a function that does all of the work for you. Just call it with the target worksheet. In most cases, you will never need any of the optional parameters. They are provided for completeness.

The code determines last row and column by using Application.Rows.Count and Application.Columns.Count to come up from the bottom and over from the far right respectively. It assumes row 1 and column A but the optional HeaderRow and TestCol parameters can be set to override that behavior. BegRow and BegCol are each optional byref and default to 1. EndRow and EndCol are also optional byref and are calculated as noted above.

The function returns True if Err.Number = 0.

```
''' <summary>
''' Removes duplicate rows from the given worksheet. All parameters are optional except for the first one.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="oSheet">The worksheet that will have duplicate rows removed.</param>
''' <param name="bActivate">Optional true to activate the worksheet, defaults to False.</param>
''' <param name="xHeader">Optional xlYesNoGuess header. Can be xlGuess, xlNo or xlYes, defaults to xlGuess.</param>
''' <param name="lBegRow">Optional ByRef BegRow, defaults to HeaderRow.</param>
''' <param name="lBegCol">Optional ByRef BegCol, defaults to 1.</param>
''' <param name="lEndRow">Optional ByRef EndRow, defaults to last row in the TestCol.</param>
''' <param name="lEndCol">Optional ByRef EndCol, defaults to last column in the HeaderRow.</param>
''' <param name="lHeaderRow">Optional ByRef HeaderRow, defaults to 1.</param>
''' <param name="lTestCol">Optional ByRef TestCol, defaults to 1.</param>
''' <param name="lErrNumber">Optional ByRef ErrNumber, defaults to 0. Will contain Err.Number.</param>
''' <param name="ErrDescription">Optional ByRef ErrDescription, defaults to empty string. Will contain Err.Description.</param>
''' <returns>Returns True if duplicate rows, if any, were successfully removed, otherwise False.</returns>
Public Function RemoveDuplicateRows(
    oSheet As Worksheet, 
    Optional bActivate As Boolean = False, 
    Optional xHeader As xlYesNoGuess = xlGuess, 
    Optional ByRef lBegRow As Long = 0, 
    Optional ByRef lBegCol As Long = 0, 
    Optional ByRef lEndRow As Long = 0, 
    Optional ByRef lEndCol As Long = 0, 
    Optional ByRef lHeaderRow As Long = 0, 
    Optional ByRef lTestCol As Long = 0, 
    Optional ByRef lErrNumber = 0, 
    Optional ByRef sErrDescription As String = vbNullString) As Boolean
On Error Resume Next
Dim sAddr1 As String, sAddr2 As String
Dim oRange As Range
    With oSheet
        If bActivate Then
            .Activate
        End If
    
        If lTestCol = 0 Then lTestCol = 1
        If lHeaderRow = 0 Then lHeaderRow = 1
    
        If lBegRow = 0 Then lBegRow = lHeaderRow
        If lBegCol = 0 Then lBegCol = 1
    
        If lEndRow = 0 Then
            lEndRow = .Cells(Application.Rows.Count, lTestCol).End(xlUp).Row
        End If
        If lEndRow > oSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count Then
            lEndRow = oSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        End If

        If lEndCol = 0 Then
            lEndCol = .Cells(lHeaderRow, Application.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        End If
        If lEndCol > oSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count Then
            lEndCol = oSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
        End If
    
        sAddr1 = .Cells(lBegRow, lBegCol).Address
        sAddr2 = .Cells(lEndRow, lEndCol).Address
    
        Set oRange = .Range(sAddr1 & ":" & sAddr2)
    
        ''Debug.Print .Name; ", BegRow:"; lBegRow; ", BegCol:"; lBegCol; ", 
                    EndRow:"; lEndRow; ", EndCol:"; lEndCol; ", RangeAddr: "; oRange.Address
    
        Call oRange.RemoveDuplicates(GetColumnsArray(lBegCol, lEndCol), Header:=xHeader)
    End With

    lErrNumber = Err.Number
    sErrDescription = Err.Description

    Set oRange = Nothing
    RemoveDuplicateRows = (Err.Number = 0)
On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```